# using Visual Stuio as IDE for third party compiler: need help for error parsing

Tags: visual-studio

We are using Visual Studio (2017) in a project (one solution) with two different configuration types: DynamicLinkLibrary and Makefile. The Makefile configuration is controlled by the maekfile of a third party compiler (Greenhills for Embedded Applications), DynamicLinkLibrary of course runs Visual Studio internally. The Makefile configuration uses the elements of the Visual Studio NMake template, for the compiler call itself there are these command lines, in which a batch file is called with transfer parameters

$(ProjectDir)..\mm.bat PLL02#$(MSBuildProjectName) bin_comp 3 LIBYES 2 /F DIAGNO

mm.bat is the batch control with seven parameters for the Greenhills compiler.

In case of a compiler error in our source code, detected by the third-party compiler, we would now like to activate a comfortable ErrorParser, which loads the corresponding source code file by double-clicking on the erroneous line in the VisualStudio output window into the source code editor window of Visual Stuido and automatically places the cursor there on the erroneous line of code. If Eclipse is used as our second IDE for our Makefile project, this works very well via a Regex control ('Regex Error Parser'). However, this does not work in Visual Studio. Is it even possible to do this directly from the output window? Does anyone have any advice here? Roughly speaking, is it at all possible to trigger an action from the Visual Studio output window by double-clicking (in the sense that the clicked line is 'read' by the output window for further processing; the further processing should ultimately display the erroneous source code line).

Best Regards, Roger

P.S.
Here is shown, what I like to know:

[Situation in error case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmyyb.png)

Comment: I don't think you can define custom error formats in VS, but it's able to parse quite a bunch of different formats already. How do the error messages look like?

Comment: Hi @PMF, see the pic (Situation in error case) in my issue description

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can make VSS understand other formats than its own.
But there is another way that works.
Format the error output of your compiler into the VSS format and put it out in the output window off VSS.

The VSS Error format ist:

```
d:\MyProg\main\Sourcefiles\myModul\src\myFile.c(2426): error C2039:
```

Maybe you have a format like this from your compiler to change to the VSS format:

```
d:\/MyProg\main\Sourcefiles/myModul/src/myFile.c", line 2426: error #136:
          struct "_Ts_braketest" has no field "braketest_stepx"
                  S_btest.braketest_stepx = 2520;
                          ^
```

The stream editor sed does a good job for such a task.
For a simple way you can format step by step with a command file for sed.
command file socToVss.sed:

```
s,\\/,\\,g                                  #replace \/ to \ (delimiter , to prevent escaping slash) 
s,\/,\\,g                                   #replace / to \ (delimiter , to prevent escaping slash) 
s/\"//g                                     #replace " to nothing
s/c,[[:space:]]line[[:space:]]/c(/g         #formating line number
s/\(([0-9]*\):/\1):/g                       #formating line number
s/\(error[[:space:]]\)#\([0-9]*\)/\1C\2/g   #formating error number
```

Example for your makefile to use the sed command file to format the errors from errors.txt to errorsVssFormat.txt and type ist out:

```
make 2> errors.txt
sed -f socToVss.sed errors.txt > errorsVssFormat.txt
type errorsVssFormat.txt
```

You can use the Open Source GNU utilities for Win32
[http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/]

Good luck with your job ;-)